# Generics class with generic properties?

Tags: c#, generics, architecture

I have a scenario where I have a bunch of jobs that I am scheduling to run at various times, the jobs themselves are being handled generically already which is great. And I have an abstract BaseJob class that they all inherit from that I use for common things (like the jobPK, startTime, exception logging, reporting, etc). But beyond that the jobs are very different, they have different properties and data associated with them that is entriely specific to them (I call these proprties JobDetails). So for example:

```
JobDetails for Job1
-customerId int
-cost double
-sku string
-userDefinedProperties SomeCustomObjectType

JobDetails for Job2
-name string
-executionDate DateTime
-otherProperties SomeOtherCustomObjectType
```

In the base class I would like to be able to store a reference to these JobDetails in as generic a fashion as possible (so in other words I don't want to just store it as object) to minimize the overhead for boxing/unboxing. Then I want to have the BaseJob class handle a lot of the common functionality that is needed for the app, so for example, if a job fails, I want to save its JobDetails to the database so that it can be restarted, I also want to log any errors that may have occured to a given job. For this I need to be able to extract those JobDetails and make use of them.

It seems like I need to make use of .NET generics and have a class of generic properties that I can stuff anything into and not have to worry about typing. What's the best way to handle this and make it efficient and flexible?

I hope that is clear, thanks for the help

Comment: Your post is detailed and clear, but I think your title could be more specific. Now it's a bit ehm generic ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like...

```
public abstract class JobBase<TDetails>
{
    private TDetails details;
    protected TDetails Details
    {
        get
        {
            if (details == null)
            {
                this.details = this.LoadDetails();
            }

            return this.details;
        }
    }

    protected virtual TDetails LoadDetails()
    {
        // Some kind of deserialization of TDetails from your DB storage.
    }
}

public class ExampleJob : JobBase<ExampleJob.ExampleJobDetails>
{
    public class ExampleJobDetails
    {
        public string ExampleProperty { get; set; }
        public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You'd either want to have tables for each type used as TDetails or one big Key/Value based table for all of them. There are pros/cons to both. If you are super paranoid about boxing, there's no reason why TDetails can't be constrained to be a struct, too.

Edit: Got it backwards, you want to save the details on a failure. How about...

```
public abstract class JobBase<TDetails>
{
    protected TDetails Details { get; private set; }

    public JobBase()
    {
        this.Details = this.CreateDetails();
    }

    protected abstract TDetails CreateDetails();

    protected void SaveDetails()
    {
        // Generic save to database.
    }
}

public class ExampleJob : JobBase<ExampleJob.ExampleJobDetails>
{
    public class ExampleJobDetails
    {
        public string ExampleProperty { get; set; }
        public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    }

    protected override ExampleJobDetails CreateDetails()
    {
        return new ExampleJobDetails() { ExampleProperty = "Hi.", AnotherProperty = 1 };
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is closer to what I am after...so I guess my question would be what would be the best design for TDetails to be able to generically handle storing and retrieving all these disparate properties and types? TDetails is a generic? Sorry I think I'm missing something

Comment: For a generic solution, you can use reflection to get the property names and their values for a given instance of the details. You could also use objects generated by Linq-to-SQL, Entity Framework or some other ORM solution, which basically does that kind of work for you.

Comment: yeah the issue I have is that the JobDetails for a given job are stored in a wrapper and then the whole thing is serialized to the database. So the JobDetails object needs to be truly generic (it can't be a job-specific instance of the JobDetails) so that I can deserialize it and use it. Its like I need the class to have generic property getters/setters but the only way I can think to do that is to back it with a generic Dictionary and then I wind up casting everything anyway

Comment: I can sympathize with wanting to avoid runtime messiness. Keep in mind however, that if you are looking for a dynamic solution that does not fit the constraints of strict typing, it is still fundamentally a runtime solution, just with cleaner syntax. If it is possible, consider having different types for your job details and a single job type that is generic, like "new Job<ExampleDetails>(details);" In general though, I find that if I cannot come up with a design that is satisfied with strict typing that there may actually be an underlying fundamental design flaw that must be addressed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `JobDetails` implement an interface and let have `BaseJob` have an abstract reference to it. Then in the actual jobs you implement the abstract `JobDetails` with the implementation you want. Then let the `JobDetails` interface define the methods `BaseJob` needs to work with. This is a slight variation on the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. It would look something like this:

```
public interface IJobDetails {
    void DoSomeWork();
}

public abstract BaseJob {

    protected abstract IJobDetails JobDetails { get; set; }

    public ExecuteJob {
        //execute the job
        JobDetails.DoSomeWork();
    }
}

public Job1 : BaseJob {

    public Job1() {
        JobDetails = new ConcreteJobDetails();
    }

    protected override IJobDetails JobDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yeah the problem with that is that the various implementations of JobDetails will have almost nothing in common so and interface design pattern doesn't make a lot of sense...they'll all have their own unique set of properties and the BaseJob class needs to be able to inspect and manipulate them

Comment: But can't you let the interface only define the methods that `BaseJob` will use? All the unique aet of properties you can put in the concrete implemetations

Comment: there will be no methods, only properties of various types that will differ dramatically between implementations...sorry if I did not make that clear in my initial post

Comment: @snappymcsnap No problem, if you think it will make things clearer, you can always edit your post.